# Ssh from outside the network keep timing out

Tags: openssl, ssh, kali-linux

So I am trying to connect to my Kali VM that run on a windows host.

I am using Virtualbox in bridge network.
my home router forward ssh to my kali VM

when I try to connect from outside the network, it just time out.
when I am in kali machine and I do tcpdump port 22

I see this

```
02:15:30.941728 IP ipX-X-X-X.no.no.cox.net.52437 > 192.168.0.248.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1048484117, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

So I kind of know it's reachine my VM at least. 
of course my ssh is running on the same port I am connecting to it and it is active and listening.

Any idea of what I might be missing?

Comment: tcpdump is getting the packages before any filters such as IPtables or other firewalls is applied. Check the firewall settings on the VM.

Comment: Even though you are using Kalil, this isn't a security question. This is just a networking question.

Comment: Can you get to the Windows 10 host this way. I need a secure entry to my own network and then have Radmin running on the Windows 10 machine to access it. If you have a Kali Guest running, you would need a like tool to access it from outside